# Dev-C++ Recipe for Target Failed

Tags: c++, gcc, dev-c++

I have a problem that really is driving me crazy right now. I have a project written in C++ and it's using pthread. I've compiled this project with Dev-C yesterday and everything was just perfect. However, today, I'm getting this nonsense "recipe for target 'project1.exe' failed" error. I didn't change anything, how come this project got broken by itself? I really don't get it. Please help me. Compile error is below:

```
> General: TDM-GCC 4.8.1 64-bit Release Building Makefile
> "E:\2013-2014\[CNG 334] OS\Course Project\New folder\Makefile.win"
> Executing  make... mingw32-make.exe -f "E:\2013-2014\[CNG 334]
> OS\Course Project\New folder\Makefile.win" all g++.exe -c main.cpp -o
> main.o -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/include"
> -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include"     -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-    w64-mingw32/4.8.1/include"
> -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32    /4.8.1/include/c++"
```

> g++.exe -c v1withupperandlowerletters.cpp -o
>   v1withupperandlowerletters.o -I"C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/include" -I"C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include" -I"C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/include"
>   -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32   /4.8.1/include/c++"
>
> g++.exe main.o v1withupperandlowerletters.o -o Project1.exe
>   -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib" -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib" -static-libgcc
>
> E:\2013-2014[CNG 334] OS\Course Project\New folder\Makefile.win:25:
>   recipe for target 'Project1.exe' failed
>
> mingw32-make.exe: *** [Project1.exe] Error 1
>
> Compilation succeeded in 4.41 seconds

Thank you very much.

Edit: Problem resolved. You can check my answer below.

Comment: I was compiling a project today and receiving this same message "recipe for target (xxx) failed". The problem was that one of the programs invoked in this target was returning a non-zero return value and suddenly the message made sense.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out strangely that my firewall program's sandbox feature was blocking Dev-C to create a new file from a project even though Dev-C++ itself was marked as a trusted program. I've disabled the sandboxing feature and it's working perfect.

I'm not deleting this topic since this may help some other person in the future. I'm using Comodo firewall and maybe other firewalls out there with sandboxing feature may raise the same problem.